# Strange font url in CSS

Tags: css, url, fonts

I found this in a css file, but I don't understand how it works?

```
@import url(/t/1.css?apiType=css&projectid=8f2a6800-87fc-4721-88c2-c4395f5c2529);
@font-face{
font-family:"Gill Sans W01_n3";
src:url("/dv2/2/2cebe80c-b289-4ae0-a3b0-baa82c6c6e10.eot?d44f19a684109620e484157aa090e818164b583323d003aed8738c486c8f2be5451a12b579fdb3b84f52c077b1b063612babe72c6cf13ea84e96a257fd04f94aa22a2e2c342ce62d6867611914a6d8b6aea98add427c897e37055b90046e50504037af165c645dd51b4dc26ecc8321d6196fc3e54c1a35c2ef7a466d10159a3ee117d8214a55b23616&projectId=8f2a6800-87fc-4721-88c2-c4395f5c2529") format("eot");
}
```

Comment: It's a URL. Which part don't you understand? You're going to have to be a lot more specific.

Comment: It's a relative URL....relative to what? it's not specified, will it even work?

Comment: No, it's not relative. It's absolute. Both of the URLs in your question are absolute. It links to a file. Are you confused about the actual URL, or the use of `src: url`, or the use of `@import url`, or using `@font-face`, or just CSS *in general*? You have to be **more specific**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, those CSS statements are creating a `@font-face`. So, the `src:url` is just linking to a file that contains the 'eot' of the font. Without the URL, the CSS does not know what the font looks like.

Comment: Okey, so this creates a font? It's not really an URL?

Comment: The point of font-face was to create custom fonts that could be used on the web. The code you have above is creating a font-family to be used and it is linking to a .eot (format created by Microsoft, and typically is kind of outdated) file. I have no idea if it will work, I don't have access to your server.

Comment: @supremo No, it's a URL. It's a URL that points to a file that *is* a font.